# Excel file corrupted on download with axios vuejs

Tags: javascript, excel, vue.js, axios, blob

I am trying to download an excel file. I have used axios for it.

I have tried the below code

```
     axios.post(backendURL + 'api/client?file_name='+file_name,params, {
        file_name: file_name
    }, {
        responseType: 'blob'
    }).then((response) => {
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data], {
            type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
        }))
        const link = document.createElement('a')
        link.href = url
        link.setAttribute('download', file_name)
        document.body.appendChild(link)
        link.click()
    });
```

I am getting the error as "Excel cannot open the file "filename.xlsx" because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file"

I have tried all the solutions which I found in google but nothing worked. Please help

Comment: Check again the excel file on your server.

Answer (score -2):

```
  downloadFile() {
            axios({
                url: this.scenario.file,  //.substring(0, this.scenario.file.lastIndexOf("/"))
                method: "GET",
                headers: {"Accept": "application/vnd.ms-excel"},
                responseType: "blob"
            }).then(response => {
                const fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
                const fileLink = document.createElement("a");

                fileLink.href = fileURL;
                fileLink.setAttribute("download", "file.xlsx");
                document.body.appendChild(fileLink);

                fileLink.click();
            });
        },
```

Comment: Please describe what the code does and maybe how it differs from the question's code. Refrain from code-only answers.

Comment: I have excel file which is preliminary uploaded

Comment: this.scenario.file is its url ="http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/datafiles/Input_curves_bm7ionE.xlsx"

Comment: Need to download it from server via url